# com.docker.supervisor cannot start Exit code 9 on mac

Tags: docker, desktop

I am unable to start docker desktop tool on mac Ventura 13.1, I keep getting fatal error
com.docker.supervisor cannot start Exit code 9
I tried already to uninstall and install docker again and also by manually removing docker files but nothing is working.
any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is where the Console program can come in handy. You'll need to find out why.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how to find out what "cannot exist code 9" is?  I am not sure what that means. so not sure why it is giving me the error and tried to search everywhere but cannot find anything related, even in the documentation

Comment: It doesn't mean a whole lot without more detail from the logs. That's why I suggested using Console.app. Search for "docker" there.